# Using AdMob and Cordova - ad is not displayed

Tags: cordova, admob

I have implemented a very simple cordova app that should show a admob ad.
It looks like this:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--
    Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
        https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
    Some notes:
        * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
        * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
        * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
            * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova!</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');


    if(AdMob) {
        AdMob.createBanner({ 
        adID: 'ca-app-pub-876613XXX/2369XXX', //my APP ad ID number for banner
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
        autoShow: true, 
        isTesting: false});
    }
    else {
        alert('No AdMob');
    }

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
```

};

app.initialize();

**config.xml**

```
...removed first line: widget id="com.example.admob" version="1.0.0" ...
<name>myTestAdMob</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
<plugin name="com.admob.plugin" spec="^5.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
```

I have tested different admob plugins as well as different ways of building the app (cordova CMD, Intel XDK).
I have tested banner as well as interstitial.
However, an ad is never shown.

In AdMob I have registered my App and added a banner to it.

Since I have tested different codes is there maybe something I miss in google admob? E.g. by now I never used the App-ID but only the App Unit ID. Do I have to put the App ID somewhere?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: See an example step by step here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova#quick-start

Comment: Hi Miquel, 
I have tested your plugin and it works out of the box! Pefect! Strange, that the other plugins do not work although I went through all steps equally.

One additional question: Will your plugin support native ads in future as well? Will native ads work in Cordova in general?

Comment: Not native ads for the moment, we are working on rewarded video ads, next months will be available :)

Comment: Hi @Miquel, i tried this plugin, but why i always get error `Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'` when build app into apk using phonegap build ?, but if i delete this plugin the app build works, can you help me?, thanks

Comment: @M.Pancadewa which plugins have you installed? Maybe you could open an issue here in order to better follow up https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/issues

Comment: Fix now by adding `<variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.8.0" />` in config.xml, thanks for your reply :)